# Using int flags in lieu of booleans

Tags: java, android

So, for example, [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) has the following flag:

```
public static final int FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL = 0x00000010;
```

This is hexadecimal for the number 16. There are other flags with values:

```
 0x00000020
 0x00000040
 0x00000080
```

Each time, it goes up by a power of 2. Converting this to binary, we get:

```
 00010000
 00100000
 01000000
 10000000
```

Hence, we can use a bitwise operators to determine which of the flags are present, etc, since each flag contains only one 1 and they are all in different locations.

**Question**:

This all makes perfect sense, but why not just use `booleans`?  Is this merely stylistic, or are there memory or efficiency benefits?

**EDIT:**
I understand that by combining them, we can store a lot of information in a single `int`.  Is this used **solely** so we can pass a lot of *boolean* type values in a single `int` instead of having to pass a ton of parameters?  I don't mean to trivialize that, it's very convenient, but are there any other benefits?

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is called a [Bit Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). One advantage is that all the information can be contained in a single variable (with no overhead like that of an ArrayList). This is useful for keeping function signatures tidy, and will have some *minor* benefits with efficiency because of fewer stack operations, but probably this will be offset by additional bitshift operations. Additionally, you can use (for example) one byte to store 8 fields rather than wasting 7 additional bytes. You can also, if you're clever with it, perform several flag checks in a single operation.

Having said that, personal preference may see the list of booleans as cleaner or preferable. Bitfields are most common in embedded systems where space is limited or something of that nature.

In reference to your edit: it's storing the *values* of the flags in ints, but those are just reference constants-- you aren't editing those, you're sticking those bits into (or out of) the `flags` field, which *is* a single int. I don't really know why they chose a bitfield for this application; perhaps someone that grew up programming space-limited microcontrollers coded that specific class. The general consensus seems to be that bitfields shouldn't be included in new code.

Comment: It says "Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user.". Of course the value of each flag is stored in a separate variable, but actually using the flag values allows storage into a single variable.
EDIT: not sure if the previous comment is deleted or just not showing up, but perhaps this comment is no longer relevant.

Comment: I've added more to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common idiom in C, where resource constraints are a much larger concern, and you usually see it in Java where the Java API is directly mapping an underlying well-known C API. However, it's not a great idea in Java for a wide number of reasons.

As of Java 5, most of the uses for one-bit bit fields are taken care of very nicely by [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), which is internally implemented using a bit field (so it's extremely fast) but is type-safe, easy to read, and `Iterable`.

Comment: Thanks, I was unfamiliar with `EnumSet` +1.